# bat file wont run in bash terminal

Tags: bash, batch-file

I have default windows CMD with its own syntax which I don't want and also git bash terminal, with a bit different syntax which I need. I have .bat file that I wrote for git bash syntax. but when I double click it it runs through windows default CMD and as a result of wrong syntax it fails. what can I do to maybe make git bash default terminal?

Comment: Why don't you rename it as a "bash" file and choose "GIT bash" as a default terminal for opening such kind of file?

Answer (score 1):

You ***DO*** realize that messing with the ***default*** command interpreter isn't a good idea? Both on Windows and Linux?

First, a batch is associated with `cmd` (in fact, `%COMSPEC%`). On Windows, files are launched accordingly to their *extension*. There is nothing like shebangs or other badly portable tricks: extension it is. So you must change this association if you want to run it through a double-click.

Second, a batch is a batch. You don't put Python code inside a `".cpp"` file, right? You don't name a PDF with a `".jpeg"` extension? So why do you put shell code into a batch file?

==> You should write a shell script (extension `".sh"` or `".bash"`) instead, and associate it properly with your bash interpreter.

BTW, you should also look at WSL2 and what it allows, if you want (near) native bash support under Windows.

Comment: didn't knew bash have its own extensions, now its a lot easier. thanks a lot

Comment: ?? Even on Linux, a **LOT** of shell scripts have a `.sh` extension... It's really not uncommon at all. Do a `find` on your Linux distro, you should find several of them. Also, take a real, serious look on WSL - you can for example try an Ubuntu 20.04 or a Debian under WSL, search that on Windows Store.